# Compiling AIR to iOS throws a java error

Tags: ios, air, flash-cs5

I have a flash app, that we are re-purposing for iPad. I can compile it happily to AIR 2, and can debug it as an iOS app (ctrl+enter, and ctrl+shift+enter) - but when I try to actually publish it I get a Java error - not a compiler error, but an error with the compiler itself if that makes sense. The error is below - sorry for any typos, but you can't copy and paste the error message:

```
Error creating files.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Method 1207 is referenced more than once.
    at abobe.abc.LLVMEmitter.referenceMethod(LLVMEmitter.java:3440)
    at abobe.abc.LLVMEmitter.access$2300(LLVMEmitter.java:44)
    at abobe.abc.LLVMEmitter$MethodEmitter.emitBlock(LLVMEmitter.java:2854)
    at abobe.abc.LLVMEmitter$MethodEmitter.emit(LLVMEmitter.java:1426)
    at abobe.abc.LLVMEmitter.emitMethods(LLVMEmitter.java:3963)
    at abobe.abc.LLVMEmitter.emit(LLVMEmitter.java:3835)
    at abobe.abc.LLVMEmitter.processABCs(LLVMEmitter.java:206)
    at abobe.abc.LLVMEmitter.generateBitcode(LLVMEmitter.java:174)
    at com.adobe.air.ipa.AOTCompiler.convertAbcToLlvmBitcode(AOTCompiler.jav a:329)
    at com.adobe.air.ipa.AOTCompiler.GenerateMacBinary(AOTCompiler.java:600)
    at com.adobe.air.ipa.IPAOutputStream.compileRootSwf(IPAOutputStream.java :196)
    at com.adobe.air.ipa.IPAOutputStream.finalizeSig(IPAOutputStream.java:35 5)
    at com.adobe.air.ADTPackager.createPackage(ADTPackager.java:65)
    at com.adobe.air.ipa.IPAPackager.createPackage(IPAPackager.java:165)
    at com.adobe.air.ADTEntrypoint.parseArgsAndGo(ADTEntrypoint.java:132)
    at com.adobe.air.ipa.PFI.parseArgsAndGo(PFI.java:152)
    at com.adobe.air.ADTEntrypoint.run(ADTEntrypoint.java:68)
    at com.adobe.air.ipa.PFI.main(PFI.java:112)
```

This happens regardless of deployment type, or rendering option. I know the certificates, and provisioning profile are correct as when I remove the Class in the .fla itself it compiles quite happily and can be put onto our dev iPad (obviously it just doesn't do anything).

Can anyone shed any light on this as I am not sure even where to start.

EDIT: This is with Flash CS5 running on XP64 if that is of any help.

Answer (score 1):

try using the ADT.BAT command, it worked for us.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure your Flash Pro CS5 is up to date: http://www.adobe.com/support/flash/downloads.html

You can post a question in the Adobe Forum here: http://www.AdobeAssistance.com

Read the Adobe FAQ for iOS (make sure you are not using unsupported libraries, etc...): http://labs.adobe.com/wiki/index.php/Packager_for_iPhone:Developer_FAQ

I would read the FAQ and make sure my Flash is up to date with the latest version and try it again. If it fails I would post this question on the Adobe Forum.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have ensured that CS5 is up to date. I think you may be right about the unsupported libraries - I was just hoping I would get an "unsupported library" error or something, rather than a non-descript "yoinks" type message. I will have to start cutting bits out until it compiles and see what I can see. I did post this to the adobe forum for the iPad packager, but no replies yet.

Answer (score 0):

It has something to do with debug information being present in the SWF. The only solution is to compile the AIR application via the command line and with the include libraries parameter:

> "c:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4\sdks\4.1.0\bin\amxmlc" .\src\YourApp.mxml -compiler.include-libraries